# Rollup + HoCs treeshaking

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, rollupjs

I'm trying to create a component library using `typescript` and `rollup`.

I have a component, `Canary`.

```js
function Canary() {
    ...
}

export default React.memo(Canary)
```

Note how `Canary` is wrapped in an HoC (`React.memo`).

I have another component, `SomeComponent`

```js
function SomeComponent() {
    ...
}

export default SomeComponent
```

If I were to build my library with just `SomeComponent` exported,

`src/index.ts`

```js
export { default as SomeComponent } from './SomeComponent'
```

The library is tree-shakeable. However, if I add component which is wrapped in an HoC, treeshaking fails. Regardless of how I import `SomeComponent` from my library, `Canary` gets pulled along with it and ends up in the bundle.

I'm using a variant of [this](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/agadoo) to detect if something it treeshakeable or not, modified for rollup.

I've found [this](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#clarifying-tree-shaking-and-sideeffects), which talks about how you can hint tools like webpack. I've setup a test project using NextJS (webpack used internally), and added `sideEffects: false` to my library's `package.json` to no avail - **However**, I don't think that it's *my code* that's breaking tree-shaking, I think it's the `React.memo` HoC. It needs to be marked *pure* in the distributable.

i.e. manually editing the output line

```
var index = React.memo(Canary);

export { index as Canary }
```

to

`var index = /*#__PURE__*/memo(Canary);`

and re-running the treeshaking test passes.

**Question** What's the proper way to signal to Rollup that you'd like to mark something pure? Am I even going at this in the right way?

Comment: Maybe this one should be opened as a ticket to their github page... Looks like you are asking for some internals, that is not common knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll do that.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you open the github issue? I can't find it. I'm also super interested in your agadoo variant, can you share it?

Comment: Hey @donzul their github specifically says that issues isn't a good place for questions like this. I ended up posting on their gitter: https://gitter.im/rollup/rollup?at=5dbc8c289c39821509c6076e. No replies yet. If nothing else, I'll ignore (sorry) their gitter suggestion and post on the issue tracker.